# Regex formation and Issue in Negation

Tags: regex

I need to create two regex

One, for catching these type of strings:

- /xyz-courses/test/test
- /abc-courses/test-abc/test-xyz
- /abc-courses/test-abc/test-xyz?itsok=yes

But I don't want to match these strings where **fixed** word is prepended with **-courses**:

- /**fixed**-courses/test/test
- /**fixed**-courses/test-abc/test-xyz
- /**fixed**-courses/test-abc/test-xyz?itsok=yes

I have created the following REGEX, which is working perfectly fine, but not sure about case  how to exclude the prepended word **fixed**

`/([^/]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`

Second, I need to create REGEX to negate all regex created in previous step.
I tried:

`[^/([^/]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)]$`

But this is showing invalid on all REGEX checkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to disallow `fixed-` before `courses`:

```sh
^/((?!fixed-)[^/-]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hvCX9g/2)

`(?!fixed-)` is a negative lookahead that will fail the match if `fixed-` appears right after `/` and before `courses/`.

For second part use this to negate first regex:

```sh
^/(?!((?!fixed-)[^/-]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$).+
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hvCX9g/4)

Comment: Can you add few valid/invalid matches for second regex then I can look into this.

Comment: Thanks a lot anubhava. India is really a place of wise people.

Comment: In that case use: `^/(?!((?!fixed-)[^/-]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$).+`

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if I can prepend a static string to all this regex. I tried some like: `[https://www.abc.me]?^/(?!((?!fixed-)[^/-]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$).+` but it didn't work

Comment: It should be: `^(https://www\.abc\.me)?/((?!fixed-)[^/-]+)-courses/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$`